# How to remove click events that have been added in Firebug console?

Tags: jquery, firebug

If I do something like this in Firebug console:

```
$(document).on("click",".my_class", function () {

// do something

});
```

Is it possible to remove this event, so that I could test other events on the same element without the first defined `on()` event running as well?

I've tried running:

```
$('.my_class').off('click');
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: first event is applied on document (event delegate) second directly on class. it should be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).off("click", ".my_class")
```

Answer (score 2):

The off must match the on, so your off doesn't have enough arguments. Try

```
$(document).off("click",".my_class");
```